# Using a 15 Amp Switch on 20 Amp Circuit

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, dimmer-switch

I know that it is to code to use two 15 Amp Receptacles on a 20 Amp breaker.

Is it acceptable to use a 15 Amp switch that controls the bathroom lights, which is on a 20 Amp breaker, along with an outlet (not switched)?

This is important because I would like to use a wifi-enabled smart dimmer switch, most of which are rated for only 15 Amps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes you can use a 15 amp switch on a 20 amp circuit but the total load needs to be less than the switch rating.

Comment: This is governed by NEC 404.14(A) BTW.